# My react js portfolio app using React Router does not load components until I refresh the page. Is there any fix to this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, web-frontend

## My react js portfolio app using React Router does not load components until I refresh the page.  Is there any fix to this?

---

I'm creating a react js portfolio website and I'm using react router for navigation.  Users navigate the site through a navbar on the left side.  [Navbar on the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FM1jo.png). When I click the different buttons, eg.about, the link changes from http://localhost:3000/ to http://localhost:3000/about but the page does not load in.  [Page after clicking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4FWn.png)  I then have to reload before the page loads in. Something intresting is when I am on the portfolio page(http://localhost:3000/portfolio)  I can switch to another page, such as contact but I can't switch back.  Anyways, can anyone help?  Here is my code.

### App.JS

```
import {Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './components/Home'
import About from './components/About'
import Contact from './components/Contact'
import Layout from './components/Layout'
import Portfolio from './components/Portfolio'
import './App.scss'

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
          <Route path="/portfolio" element={<Portfolio />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

### index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import App from './App'
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
    ,
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)

reportWebVitals()
```

### SideBar - index.js

```
import './index.scss'
import LogoS from '../../assets/images/logo-s.png'
import LogoSubtitle from '../../assets/images/logo_sub.png'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import {
  faInstagram,
  faGithub,
  faYoutube,
  faDiscord,
} from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'
import { faHome, faUser, faEnvelope, faSuitcase } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

const Sidebar = () => {
  return (
    <div className="nav-bar">
      <Link className="logo" to="/">
        <img src={LogoS} alt="Logo" />
        <img className="sub-logo" src={LogoSubtitle} alt="Mindque" />
      </Link>
      <nav>
        <NavLink exact="true" activeclassname="active" to="/">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} color="#4d4d4e" />
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink activeclassname="active" className="about-link" to="/about">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUser} color="#4d4d4e" />
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink activeclassname="active" className="portfolio-link" to="/portfolio">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSuitcase} color="#4d4d4e" />
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink
          activeclassname="active"
          className="contact-link"
          to="/contact"
        >
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEnvelope} color="#4d4d4e" />
        </NavLink>
      </nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a
            href="https://www.instagram.com/mindqueblast/"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noreferrer"
          >
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faInstagram} color="#4d4d4e" />
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a
            href="https://github.com/MindqueBlast"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noreferrer"
          >
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faGithub} color="#4d4d4e" />
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a
            href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC9QYALAwUUxW21PASjhxagQ"
            rel="noreferrer"
            target="_blank"
          >
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faYoutube} color="#4d4d4e" />
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://discordapp.com/users/694984812062310421" rel="noreferrer" target="_blank">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faDiscord} color="#4d4d4e" />
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Sidebar
```

***Thank you!***

Comment: You are missing a '/' in front of about in your routes. Have you tried adding that?
That might not be the problem. Can you check the console for erros?

Comment: I put a '/' in front of about but it still does not change.  The console displays no errors.  Something that I found though, is when I'm on the portfolio page I can use the navbar and I don't need to refresh but only for that page.

Comment: Where is the `Sidebar` component rendered?

Comment: @DrewReese
`import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'
import Sidebar from '../Sidebar/'
import './index.scss'

const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Sidebar />
      <div className="page">
        <span className="tags top-tags">&lt;body&gt;</span>

        <Outlet />
        <span className="tags bottom-tags">
          &lt;/body&gt;
          <br />
          <span className="bottom-tag-html">&lt;/html&gt;</span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Layout
`

Comment: Do you mind trying to reproduce it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-fmk4ui
In my experiment it's working just fine.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was curious if `Sidebar` was bing rendered within the routing context, and then also if `Layout` was rendering an `Outlet` for the nested routes. I don't see any overt issues in the code you've shared. Think you could create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces this issues that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: @DrewReese
I have too many files
https://github.com/MindqueBlast/portfolio

packages needed to install

npm i @emailjs/browser
npm i @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons
npm i @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
npm i @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
npm i animate.css
npm i gsap-trial
npm i loaders.css
npm i react-leaflet
npm i react-loaders
npm i react-router-dom
npm i sass

Comment: @julianobrasil
I have too many files
https://github.com/MindqueBlast/portfolio

packages needed to install

npm i @emailjs/browser
npm i @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons
npm i @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
npm i @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
npm i animate.css
npm i gsap-trial
npm i loaders.css
npm i react-leaflet
npm i react-loaders
npm i react-router-dom
npm i sass

Comment: Are any of those relevant for a basic routing/navigation example? The repo is missing a package.json file.

Comment: @DrewReese
npm i react-loaders
npm i react-router-dom

everything else is just the packages i installed for my project

Comment: @DrewReese
added the other files i frgt too

Comment: Funny, I thought the code in your repo looked familiar after digging into it. I answered another question about a month ago that had the exact same issue with the `useEffect` hooks and returning the `setTimeout` result. Is this code related to some tutorial or React course?

Comment: Here's a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/my-react-js-portfolio-app-using-react-router-does-not-load-components-until-i-re-ivfqw8) fork of your repo with the fix applied.

Comment: @DrewReese  Yea, I'm using a youtube tutorial.  Thank you so much for the fix!